# Find the next 8 dates that are Mondays (exclusive of today)

Tags: javascript, datetime

Any thoughts on improving this method of finding the next 8 Mondays not including today?

```js
var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);
app.controller("appController", function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.mondays = [];

  var MILLISECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    now = new Date(),
    nowTime = now.getTime(),
    mondayOffset = 7 - (now.getDay() - 1);

  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    $scope.mondays.push(
      new Date(nowTime + ((MILLISECONDS_IN_A_DAY * mondayOffset) + (MILLISECONDS_IN_A_DAY * 7 * i)))
    );
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="appController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="date in mondays track by $index">{{date | date}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may have a bug (depends on how the calculation should work). If today is a Sunday, the `mondayOffset` will be `7 - (0 - 1) == 8`, meaning the entire upcoming week will be skipped. In other words, `mondayOffset` will always be in the range 2-8. I'm guessing that's not what you want.

When dealing with dates, I find it simpler to deal with them as just dates, rather than as millisecond timestamps. Also, with timestamp arithmetic there's always the risk of time zones messing things up for you (for instance when going to/from daylight savings time).

Besides a millisecond number, [the `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) also accepts separate arguments for year, month, date, hour, etc.. The neat thing is that if you pass a date that doesn't exist, like June 33rd, it'll automatically roll over to July 3rd.

So you can just increment the date argument as needed to produce valid dates in the future:

```js
var app = angular.module("angularApp", []);
app.controller("appController", function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.mondays = [];

  var today  = new Date(),
      year   = today.getFullYear(),
      month  = today.getMonth(),
      date   = today.getDate(),
      offset = 8 - (today.getDay() || 7); // days till next Monday

  for(var i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++) {
    $scope.mondays.push( new Date(year, month, date + offset + 7 * i) );
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="angularApp" ng-controller="appController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="date in mondays track by $index">{{date | date}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here the `offset` will be in the range 1-7, so if today's a Sunday, it'll only skip 1 day ahead.

Comment: Awesome catch on the offset.  My only concern with your change is performance hurts pretty badly, although the readability might make up for it since we're likely talking about suboptimization here.  http://jsperf.com/nextmondaysof8 Thanks for the input!

Comment: @sonicblis Wow, that's quite a difference in speed, I admit. I'd take that performance hit though (unless it turns out to be huge bottleneck, but I doubt you're doing these calculations thousands of times). I kinda doubt it's noticeable. Besides the readability, also note the added safety w.r.t. time zones.

Comment: Considering I could run it ~332 times in a second, I think we're gonna be ok.  Thanks again!